# doubts using array and switch in?

Tags: c, arrays, switch-statement

What is the role of statement `ndigit[c-'0']`?
i am using ansi c.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int c, i, ndigit[10];
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        ndigit[i]=0;
    while((c = getchar())!= EOF)
    {
        switch(c)
        {
            case '0' :case '1' :case '2' :case '3' :case '4' :case '5' :case '6' :case '7' :case '8' :case '9' : ndigit[c-'0']++;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("digits=");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++) printf("%d",ndigit[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi:-) welcome to StackOverflow (SO) .please (next time) add the language you're using. cuz arrays can be in many languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

c is an ascii character value (although stored in an integer type). e.g. character '0' is 48 in [ascii](http://www.asciitable.com/), so if getchar returns character '0' then c will have the integer value 48.

c - '0' does a subtraction of the two character values (ok, it converts '0' to integer 48 before subtracting), giving an integer ready to index into the array.

So char '1' becomes integer 1, char '2' becomes integer 2, etc.

It is just a quick way of converting from ascii character values to integer values, for a known set of values. It would have strange results for characters outside the expected range '0'-'9' - e.g. if you did this with character '+' you would get -5 which is not a good array index.  However that is OK because the switch statement checks it is in the range '0' - '7'.

Comment: pls dont mind if i m wrong .. but c is declared as int ??? a lil bit more explanation will be helpful .thanx

Comment: ok, you're right - I will update my answer.  It's still true though - just c is an int holding the integer value of the character, which it got from getchar()

Comment: well explained ... thanx